# Dynamic redirects with Gatsby

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, redirect, gatsby, server-side

Given a Gatsby application with dynamically generated product urls on build:

- /product/x/
- /product/x/variant1/
- /product/x/variant2/
- /product/y/
- /product/y/variant1/
- ...

Is there a way to automatically cause access to non-existing sub-urls of each product to redirect to the root of that product? Preferably on the server-side (`gatsby-ssr.js`).

Like this:

- /product/x/variantdoesnotexist/ => /product/x/
- /product/x/* => /product/x/ (When * is not a valid url part)
- /product/y/variantdoesnotexist/ => /product/y/
- ...

Only found a client-side solution so far, which includes checking path in the 404 page template and doing a conditional `window.location.assign`. This is not very optimal as it flashes the 404 page before redirecting and does not perform a 302/301 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `createRedirect` action in the `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
    const { createRedirect } = actions;
    
    createRedirect({
    fromPath: `/product/*/foo`,
    toPath: `/product/*`,
  });
}
```

Tweak it as you wish, you can use your current redirects rules within `createRedirect`.

Keep in mind that in `createPages` is where you create all dynamic pages hence you have all the slugs and paths available to make your dynamic redirects.

More details: https://support.gatsbyjs.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500003051241-Working-with-Redirects-and-Rewrites

Comment: Thanks for tip! I see that I was not specific enough in my post - have updated it.
Using the `createRedirect` this would yield dynamically creating redirects like this:

`/product/x/*` => `/product/x/` (unless the * part match an existing variant)

Seems like Gatsby has page precedence over redirects, so just that redirect for each product might work.

Comment: However, I saw that having redirect with `*` did an exact match for the wildcard. 
Ie `/product/x/*/` => `/product/x/`, but not for `/product/x/variantdoesnotexists/`.

This might be something I'll have to resolve where the application is hosted. Got any experience with that when it's being hosted with Cloudfront in AWS?

Comment: It's more like a `.htaccess` redirect rule or AWS redirections. I haven't enough knowledge in that devops side